# Efficent Pagination With Less Hassle?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, get, pagination

I am trying to build a pagination that will be easy to the users to use and also for me to modify, I am programming a clan feature similar to the facebook group feature and what I want to allow is users can block certain users that they don't want from seeing there certain posts now the only issue is here I don't use queries I just return something as false

So for Example:

```
if($user_on_block_for_current_post) {
$post = false;
}
//echo the posts that the current is not blocked viewing (this is all in a while loop i don't specify a loop though) 
echo $post;
```

The Method:

Now after basically explaining why I prefer my method that's easy and more professional and don't need to be modified.

in he url it will specify a limit for example ?group_name=some_group&limit=10

that will only display 10 posts and when a user clicks "Load More" it will change limit=10 to limit=20 the only issue here say if a certain clan had 1 Million posts and the user wanted to load 1 million or 2 billion posts at once i'm worried it might crash the site or slow down the database.

I also though about using JQuery to load more posts (like the facebook scroll pagination) but that seems complex to implement :/

so how would I be able to add the jquery method or would loading 2-8 billion posts etc slow down the site?

Thanks!

Comment: you would load 2 billion posts the same way you do 100,000 posts...just do it!

Comment: so it won't slow down the site if i loaded 2 billion posts/data/accounts etc?? 
if so I do it :D